# RedirectStandardOutput showing result after process closed C#(Not showing output line by line)

Tags: c#, ipc

I am trying to read output from other process at real time line by line. But it showing output after process stop/closed. I am not sure what is wrong. I am trying to execute python exe. Here is my code:

```
var info = new ProcessStartInfo();
info.FileName = "main.exe";
info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
info.RedirectStandardError = true;
info.UseShellExecute = false;
Process other = new Process();
other.StartInfo = info;
other.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(NetOutputDataHandler);
other.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(NetErrorDataHandler);
other.Start();
other.BeginOutputReadLine();
other.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow ;-) `BeginOutputReadLine` reads - as the name already suggest's - lines. So if there is no newline detected in the output stream, the `OutputDataReceived`-Event will not be fired. If you need to read the data even if there is no newline in the stream, you can manually poll the stream. Can you confirm that there are newline characters in your output?

Comment: @MarkusSafar there is new line . I am printing output like print('Number of arguments:. \n')

Comment: I am using \n in print statement. So it always begin newline.

Comment: Fixed this error using flush output. If output not showing line by line, using flash output. It will fix issue.